# Motion (daemon) as webcam, picture on command

Tags: webcam, motion

I have Motion running as Daemon to use a webcam in my local network.
This is not used for motion detecting, just to have a livestream.

I want to take a photo when a button is pressed on the webserver.

So **I am looking for a command to save the current frame in Motion to an image** (e.g. jpg).

Or would using Motion be rather resource consuming when only using it to set up a livestream? Any suggestions for better alternatives?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the solution myself.

For future reference, here is the solution:

The page `http://RPI.IP:CONFIGPORT/0/action/snapshot` already executes the necessary code to make a snapshot. Calling this page (e.g. cURL) then enables you to take a snapshot when desired.